# How to get HTTP status on error response, while using Angular HttpClient?

Tags: angular, typescript, http

With below code, I'm able to get HTTP status for success response only:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
this.http.post<any>(apiUrl, params, {
  observe: 'response',
}).subscribe(
  re => console.log(re),
  err => console.warn(err)
}
...
```

..for success response I get separate `re.body` and `re.status`, but for "err" I get only string describing error.

How to get in `err` similar structure as in `re`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
err => {
  console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
  console.log(`Error code ${err.status}, body : ${err.error}`);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't help, getting "Cannot read property 'message' of undefined"

Comment: Please `console.log(err)` and show the console result

Comment: to trigger error I tried to call not existing API endpoint, and it gives e.g. "Not Found" as string

Comment: Do you have any `interceptor` in your project?

Comment: Yes, that was it! I have error interceptor to catch generic API errors,which was modifying error before re-throwing it.After fixing that's solved, thanks much!